# can we import more than one tables in sqoop by giving different where conditions?

Tags: sqoop

I need to import more than one tables from rdbms by giving some where conditions.
how can i import 2 different tables from 2 different location and put into 2 different locations in hdfs.

Comment: please suggest.

Comment: can you add example - sample tables, query, etc?

Comment: let 2 tables A and B are present in a database. where i need to import tables with --table A -- where colmn_1>5....and also --table B --where column_2>10..can i perform this in a single sqoop job?

Comment: No you have to run two separate jobs for that.

Comment: no its not possible. you can either used import or import-all-table.you can import two table with the help of import-all-tables but you can not able to used where condition with two tables.